# Como posso apresentar o resultado dos acertos noutra página?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

```js
function checar() {
  

  var questao1 = document.quiz.questao1.value;
  var questao2 = document.quiz.questao2.value;
  var questao3 = document.quiz.questao3.value;
  var questao4 = document.quiz.questao4.value;
  var questao5 = document.quiz.questao5.value;
  var questao6 = document.quiz.questao6.value;
  var questao7 = document.quiz.questao7.value;
  var questao8 = document.quiz.questao8.value;
  var questao9 = document.quiz.questao9.value;
  var questao10 = document.quiz.questao10.value;

  var correto = 0;


  if (questao1 == "Luigi") {
    correto++;
  }
  if (questao2 == "Nintendo") {
    correto++;
  }
  if (questao3 == "Bowser") {
    correto++;
  }
  if (questao4 == "Encanador") {
    correto++;
  }
  if (questao5 == "Verdadeira") {
    correto++;
  }
  if (questao6 == "Pular") {
    correto++;
  }
  if (questao7 == "Peach") {
    correto++;
  }
  if (questao8 == "Cogumelo") {
    correto++;
  }
  if (questao9 == "TDragão") {
    correto++;
  }
  if (questao10 == "Bowser Jr") {
    correto++;
  }


  var imagens = ["img/ganhar.gif", "img/maisoumenos.gif", "img/perdeu.gif"];
  var mensagens = ["Mandou bem!", "É...melhor tentar de novo!", "Tente novamente!"];
  var pontos;

  if (correto == 0) {
    pontos = 2;
  }

  if (correto > 0 && correto < 10) {
    pontos = 1;
  }

  if (correto == 10) {
    pontos = 0;
  }

  document.getElementById("enviar").style.visibility = "visible";

  document.getElementById("mensagem").innerHTML = mensagens[pontos];

  document.getElementById("num_correto").innerHTML = "Você tem " + correto + " correto.";

  document.getElementById("imagem").src = imagens[pontos];
}
```

```css
body {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

#quiz {
  margin-left: 10px;
  background: rgb(189, 118, 118);
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  width: 450px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Quiz</title>
  <link href="Quiz.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="Quiz.js"></script>
</head>


<body>

  <h1>Quiz de clássicos dos video-games! </h1>


  <form id="quiz" name=quiz>

    <p class="questoes">1- Mário tem um irmão, seu nome é:</p>
    <input type="radio" id="q" name="questao1" value="Luigi"> Luigi <br>
    <input type="radio" id="q" name="questao1" value="Rodrigo"> Rodrigo <br>
    <input type="radio" id="q" name="questao1" value="Tails"> Tails <br>
    <input type="radio" id="q" name="questao1" value="Ambrósio"> Ambrósio <br>


    <br>
    <br>
    <p class="questoes">2- Mário é um personagem de jogos da franquia de qual empresa?</p>
    <input id="textbox" type="text" name="questao2">


    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p class="questoes">3- A princesa dos games sempre é sequestrada por um inimigo do Mário, cujo nome é:</p>
    <input type="radio" id="q" name="questao3" value="Browser"> Browser <br>
    <input type="radio" id="q" name="questao3" value="Bowser"> Bowser <br>
    <input type="radio" id="q" name="questao3" value="Bauser"> Bauser <br>
    <input type="radio" id="q" name="questao3" value="Bauster"> Bauster <br>

    <br>
    <br>
    <p class="questoes">4- Qual é a profissão do personagem Mário?</p>
    <input type="radio" id="q" name="questao4" value="Bombeiro"> Bombeiro <br>
    <input type="radio" id="q" name="questao4" value="Joalheiro"> Joalheiro <br>
    <input type="radio" id="q" name="questao4" value="Musico"> Musico <br>
    <input type="radio" id="q" name="questao4" value="Encanador"> Encanador <br>

    <br>
    <br>
    <p class="questoes">5- Em algumas fases do jogo, podemos encontrar canos que nos levam a outros mundos. Esta afirmação é:</p>
    <input type="radio" id="q" name="questao5" value="Verdadeira"> Verdadeira <br>
    <input type="radio" id="q" name="questao5" value="Falsa"> Falsa <br>

    <br>
    <br>
    <p class="questoes">6- O que temos que fazer para matar o inimigo na maioria dos jogos de plataforma do Mário?
    </p>
    <input type="radio" id="q" name="questao6" value="Pular"> Pular sobre a cabeça do inimigo <br>
    <input type="radio" id="q" name="questao6" value="Atirar"> Atirar no inimigo <br>
    <input type="radio" id="q" name="questao6" value="Queimar"> Queimar o inimigo <br>
    <input type="radio" id="q" name="questao6" value="Fugir"> Não se mata o inimigo, apenas se foge dele <br>

    <br>
    <br>
    <p class="questoes">7- Qual o nome da princesa que o Mário tem que resgatar em quase todos os jogos?</p>
    <input type="radio" id="q" name="questao7" value="Rosalina"> Rosalina <br>
    <input type="radio" id="q" name="questao7" value="Daisy"> Daisy <br>
    <input type="radio" id="q" name="questao7" value="Pauline"> Pauline <br>
    <input type="radio" id="q" name="questao7" value="Peach"> Peach <br>

    <br>
    <br>
    <p class="questoes">8- Qual o item que o Mário come para crescer nos jogos?</p>
    <input type="radio" id="q" name="questao8" value="Banana"> Banana <br>
    <input type="radio" id="q" name="questao8" value="Cogumelo"> Cogumelo <br>
    <input type="radio" id="q" name="questao8" value="Morango"> Morango <br>
    <input type="radio" id="q" name="questao8" value="Espinafre"> Espinafre <br>

    <br>
    <br>
    <p class="questoes">9- O que é o inimigo do Mário, Bowser?</p>
    <input type="radio" id="q" name="questao9" value="Taturana"> Uma taturana <br>
    <input type="radio" id="q" name="questao9" value="Morcego"> Um morcego <br>
    <input type="radio" id="q" name="questao9" value="Dragão"> Um dragão <br>
    <input type="radio" id="q" name="questao9" value="TDragão"> Uma tartaruga dragão <br>

    <br>
    <br>
    <p class="questoes">10- Qual o nome do filho do inimigo Bowser?</p>
    <input type="radio" id="q" name="questao10" value="Bowser Jr"> Bowser Jr <br>
    <input type="radio" id="q" name="questao10" value="KidBowser"> Kid Bowser <br>
    <input type="radio" id="q" name="questao10" value="NanoBowser"> Nano Bowser <br>
    <input type="radio" id="q" name="questao10" value="KoopaBowser"> Koopa Bowser <br>
    <br>
    <br>


    <input id="botao" type="button" value="Concluir" onclick="checar();">

  </form>

  <div id="enviar">
    <p id="num_correto"></p>
    <p id="mensagem"></p>
    <img id="imagem">
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

**A questão é:**

Se rodarmos o script, ao clicar em checar, na mesma página onde é mostrado as perguntas do quiz, mostrará também o número de acertos. Eu gostaria de que, nessa página permanecesse o quiz e ao clicar no botão checar, abrisse e/ou atualizasse a pagina com o número de acertos.

Espero ter sido claro, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser possível resolver esse problema(armazenamento de dados) através da utilização do objeto [Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Storage) do navegador, manipulando através da propriedade [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/Window.localStorage), que é extremamente simples de usar baseado na ideia de *chave:valor*.

E para o redirecionamento da página é possível utilizar  o  [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Location) disponível através de [Window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/location).

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Não consegui compreender muito bem a parte do Storage e LocalStorage. A parte do window.location eu compreendi e consigo fazer com que apareça em outra página o gabarito desse quiz, mas ainda não o total de acertos como solicitado. No entanto, já lhe agradeço.

Comment: Usando JS você pode colher os dados numa página(das perguntas) e gerar a soma das respostas corretas (variável 'correto'). Depois disso você pode pegar o valor dessa variável e enviar para o localStorage através do JS e só então redirecionar a página.
Já na página redirecionada você busca esse dados e apresenta para o usuário.

Answer (score 0):

Uma possível solução, sem depender de rotas e outras configurações e mantendo-se apenas com JavaScript *vanilla*, uma vez que não especificas e devo presumir.

```
// Abre nova janela e grava a janela numa variável para que a possas manipular posteriormente

    const novaJanela = window.open();
```

A partir do momento que já tens uma outra janela (desde que se mantenha na mesma origem, domínio) poderás ter acesso direto e modificar o seu conteúdo.

```
// Adiciona texto à nova janela

    novaJanela.document.body.innerText = "Este texto aparece na nova janela"
```

Tendo isto em consideração é usar a criatividade.
No que diz respeito ao passar dados para a nova página o mesmo conceito se aplica. A estrutura de dados é que poderá ter que ser adaptada para facilitar a implementação. O recomendado talvez fosse criares um objeto que podias mapear na nova janela.

Poderás também adicionar parâmetros para poderes personalizar a nova janela, como dimensões, nome da janela, etc. Deixo a documentação da w3schools para poderes dar uma olhada.

Dá também uma olhada na documentação do objeto [Window](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp).

Referências

- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp
  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp